# Deploy to Azure Website from Appveyor

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, psake, appveyor

I have a web application that I am trying to deploy from appveyor to an azure website. I have the build configured in appveyor to use a psake script. From the appveyor documentation, it seems that I need to select "Package Web Applications for Web Deploy" from the build tab, but since I am using a psake script I am unable to make this selection. How can I do this while continuing to use my psake script?

Am I on the right path to perform a deployment to an azure website? I am fairly new to both psake and appveyor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppVeyor's built-in Web Deploy provider is able to deploy from both Web Deploy package and a regular .zip archive. You can use `7z.exe` to package your app and then push it to artifacts: http://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts